# querySelector for extended component does not work

Tags: lightning-web-components, parent-to-child, queryselector

I have a class which extends a Datatable.
From there I want to call the child component, but the querySelector is always empty.
It is working for other component which are not extended.
I want to  call a function in the rendered callback from the component
extentedTable.js

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import imageTemplate from './templates/image.html';
import { api} from 'lwc';


export default class ExtentedTable extends LightningDatatable {

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('rendered callback from extended table');
        this.template.querySelector("c-image");
        element.hideThumbnails();
        // console.log('element '+element.length);
  }
      //Let's create the Custom Type for the different types
static customTypes = {
    image: {  // the name of the new datatype
        template: imageTemplate, // The HTML file that will get rendered
        typeAttributes: ['height', 'width', 'alt']  // the attribute of custom data type that we have created
    }
};
}
```

templates/image.html

```
<template>
<c-image class="test" lwc:ref="myDiv" image-url={value} width={typeAttributes.width} height={typeAttributes.height}
    alt={typeAttributes.alt}></c-image>
</template>
```

image.html

```
<template>
<img class="slds-p-around_xxx-small thumbnail_img" src={imageUrl} width={height} height={width} alt={alt}
    onclick={handleThumbnailClick} />
</template>
```

image.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Image extends LightningElement {
@api imageUrl;
@api height;
@api width;
@api alt;

@api hideThumbnails(){
    console.log('hideThumbnails');
    this.template.querySelector('.thumbnail_img').remove('thumbnail_img');

}
}
```

Any ideas how to call the hideThumbnail Methode from image.js?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but do you get results back from this.querySelectorAll instead of this.template.querySelectorAll?

Comment: Tried that as well. No results.